# macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 empty trash sound playing repeatedly

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, high-sierra, unix

I am trying to figure out how to convert a piece of sheet music to XML file for a student. I heard about Pizzicato app for macOS. I downloaded it, and then attempted to use it (couldn't figure it out). When I closed Pizzicato app, (it was using Terminal.app) and then deleted it, it kept making the trash can sound over and over again.

Did I mess something up by not following a procedure correctly? I don't know anything about Unix/macOS, other than it's reference in Jurassic Park ;) This is a brand new MacBook and I'm nervous something's awry. I restarted it right after it started making the sound and it did it well, and it feels like all the programs are running OK.

Should I take it in to have someone look at it?

Comment: If you open activity monitor and search for the app name, do you see anything? I think it’s safe to assume the restart cleaned things up, just wondering if there’s anything lingering.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to perform all your other tasks normally just like before and no longer hear the trash sound, you should be fine and there should be nothing to worry about.

Do test that the other audio is playing fine. You can also attempt to create a temporary file/folder, move it to trash and empty it to ensure that the sound plays only once.

Since restarting your computer has fixed the issue, it was most likely due to some bug in macOS High Sierra.

In cases like this, restarting is the first resort towards fixing.